# "Property 'name' does not exist on type" typescript problem in react website

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, typescript, object

I'm trying to do a simple e-commerce website in React with Typescript (my first React and Typescript website). I have a list of products and when I press the product I go to the product page. I ran into a problem when trying to display information about the product on the page.

I am fetching data from my RESTful API and I can console.log the correct product and all its information - but I can not return the name, price, image etc on the page. When trying to use data.name I get two errors "Object is possibly 'undefined'" and "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'CartItemType[]".

Can anybody help? I've tried loads of different approaches but I can't get it to display the information - only the productid through match.params.productId.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter, Link, match, NavLink, Route, Switch, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useQuery } from "react-query";

export type CartItemType = {
    productId: number;
    category: string;
    description: string;
    img_path: string;
    price: number;
    name: string;
    quantity: number;
  };

const ProductDetails = ({match}: {match: any}) => {
      const getProduct = async (): Promise<CartItemType[]> =>
      await (await fetch('http://localhost:3000/products/'+ match.params.productId)).json(); 
      const {data} = useQuery<CartItemType[]>(
        'product',
        getProduct
      );

      if(data){
        console.log(data) //gives me the correct product based on URL. For example: 
{productId: 12, name: "Green tea", price: 40, img_path: "Images/Teas/12.png", description: "Tasting notes: Cool mint}
        
console.log(data.name) //gives the error "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'CartItemType[]
      }

return (
  <div>
 <p>Product name: {data.name}</p> // gives error "Object is possibly 'undefined' and "Property 'name' does not exist on type 'CartItemType[]
</div>
)
}

export default ProductDetails
```

Comment: Should be `useQuery<CartItemType>` (without `[]`), since you are requesting a single item, no?

Comment: It looks like you're telling the compiler that `data` is an array `CartItemType[]`. You appear to be expecting it to just be an object (`CartItemType`).

Comment: @moonwave99 Oh god! Thank you so much to all of you. I had a feeling I was just missing something stupid :) This worked. And I've also just added "{data?.name}" in my return, so that I don't get the "undefined" error anymore :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are fetching one specific item from `'http://localhost:3000/products/'+ match.params.productId`, which returns one specific object like:
`{productId: 12, name: "Green tea", price: 40, img_path: "Images/Teas/12.png", description: "Tasting notes: Cool mint}`

But you told typescript that it'll return an array of items here: `CartItemType[]`

So when you do `console.log(data.name)`, typescript infers it to be `[].name` and complains arrays don't have a `name` property.

Update usages of `CartItemType[]` to  just `CartItemType`

Comment: Thank you! I had a feeling I was just missing something minor. I also ended up using
"{data?.name}" in my return, so that I don't get the "undefined" error anymore :)